# Checked box value not retained in code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have gridview with checkbox column and one Select all checkbox outside the gridview. I have used javascript to check all checkbox within the grid  when Select all checkbox is checked.
I am able to check and uncheck all checkbox of gridview. But while  i click save button the states of all those checkbox within the grid is false so that i could not save the datas.

Code i have used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectAllCheckboxes(chk) {
        $('#<%=grvmembers.ClientID %>').find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
            if (this != chk) {
                this.checked = chk.checked;
            }

        });
</script>
```

Comment: You are probably binding the grid to the data source on the page load.  Can you show us the code for data binding ?

Comment: @Habib actually gridview is in usercontrol and i am using that usercontrol as pop up from main page. And I have bind the source  of gridview in usercontrol

Answer (score 0):

**Details:** Sounds like you haven't checked for IsPostBack

**Solution:** Add to your Page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      // Your initial setup
   }
}
```